# Convert the names of numeric numpy arrays to a list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, type-conversion, filenames

I want to convert the names of numeric numpy arrays to a list. I'll use the list to feed a pandas column statement. Here is an example of what I want:

```
import numpy as np

#Data
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

list = [a , b]
print(list)
```

`[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]` << This is what I get

`['a' , 'b']` << This is what I want (a list of variable names)

I've tried converting Data to string, e.g.:

```
new = str(list) but get
print(new)
```

`[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`

I've also tried

```
ab= np.concatenate((a, b), axis=None).astype(str)
print(ab)
```

`['1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6']`

What I want is:
`['a', 'b']`

Comment: If you know the variable names, you can just write `list = ['a', 'b']`. When don't you know the variable names?

Comment: In most cases the answer is that you don't really want that. Try to place the arrays as values in a dictionary with their "names" as keys. Then you can easily access the dictionary to retrieve the desired data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use a dictionary instead, especially if you want to use it to create a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

#Data
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b':b})
```

Output:

```
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `locals` "magic" dictionary that contains the names of all local variable together with their value:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> list_ = [a, b]
>>> [name for name, val in locals().items() if val in list_]
['a', 'b']
```

This is mostly a curiosity about the Python language, I suggest to solve your problem by following the suggestion of @Suraj Shourie as it is simpler and more readable and it does the same thing in the end.

Comment: The above code works when it is the only thing in my Jupyter Notebook , But when I add it to my Notebook that contains other calculations I get the following error:

Comment: /var/folders/14/gy7rs80n3fsdn2n5r1dvyvn80000gn/T/ipykernel_9616/4210420702.py:2: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  var_names =[name for name, val in locals().items() if val in vars_]

Comment: And sometimes get this error too: /var/folders/14/gy7rs80n3fsdn2n5r1dvyvn80000gn/T/ipykernel_9616/1004182724.py:7: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  [name for name, val in locals().items() if val in list_]